# parse a json with json.net but something wrong guess

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Ankara,tr this is current json data, first i create it with json 2 c# i get this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace weatherSample
{
    public class service
    {
        public service ()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Coord
    {
        public double lon { get; set; }

        public double lat { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sys
    {
        public int type { get; set; }

        public int id { get; set; }

        public double message { get; set; }

        public string country { get; set; }

        public int sunrise { get; set; }

        public int sunset { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string main { get; set; }

        public string description { get; set; }

        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainWeather
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }

        public int pressure { get; set; }

        public int humidity { get; set; }

        public double temp_min { get; set; }

        public double temp_max { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }

        public int deg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clouds
    {
        public int all { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Coord coord { get; set; }

        public Sys sys { get; set; }

        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }

        public string @base { get; set; }

        public MainWeather main { get; set; }

        public Wind wind { get; set; }

        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }

        public int dt { get; set; }

        public int id { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public int cod { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now i try to parse but i get some trouble,

```
WebClient webC = new WebClient (link);

var jsonDatas = JObject.Parse (y);

var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <MainWeather> (y);

Console.Write (c.temp);
```

it returns 0 value

what should be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deserialize into an instance of `RootObject` instead:

```
RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(y);
```

Then access the `MainWeather` property:

```
Console.Write(result.main.temp);
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/LWfHrH

If you just care about the `MainWeather` object, you could also do this:

```
MainWeather r = JObject.Parse(y)["main"].ToObject<MainWeather>();
```

Comment: yes, suprisely i find it yet, thanks for info btw :), is it for all json datas,? need to use from top?

Comment: @HâlukYilmaz: Do you mean do you always have to deserialize to `RootObject` like that?

Comment: yeah dear Andrew, sorry for bad pronounce, i am exactly try to say what you mean, beacuse i allways get null or 0 before use from child

Comment: wow, just amazing, i wish able to can click to accepted message lots of more, i was try for a while but i was trying like          JObject o = JObject.Parse (jsondata);
 and console.write(o["temp]); .. anyway really thanks so much